# React - Cannot get property setState of null

Tags: reactjs, redux, setstate

I am intending to get snapshot val from Firebase within my React component. I want to get the values based on init of the component and attach a listener for changes.

```
class ChatMessages extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
    };
    this.getMessages = this.getMessages.bind(this);
}

getMessages(event) {
  const messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');
  messagesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    this.setState({ messages: snapshot.val() });
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getMessages();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <ul>
            <li>Default Chat Message</li>
            { this.state.messages }
          </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because 'this' is losing its context. So that, 'this.setState' is being undefined. You can have a reference for the actual 'this' via a variable called 'that'.

```
class ChatMessages extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
    };
    this.getMessages = this.getMessages.bind(this);
}

getMessages(event) {
  const messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');
  let that = this
  messagesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    // here 
    that.setState({ messages: snapshot.val() });
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getMessages();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <ul>
            <li>Default Chat Message</li>
            { this.state.messages }
          </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

Or if possible, you can use arrow function, which keeps its context.

```
getMessages(event) {
  const messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');
  // here
  messagesRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    // here 
    that.setState({ messages: snapshot.val() });
  });
}
```

Comment: forgot the power of the arrow function! that did the trick, thanks!